# Setup project, custom install class overriding OnBeforeInstall, OnAfterInstall

Tags: c#, deployment, installation, setup-project

I’m working on a setup project and have my own custom installer class in a separate library. From within my custom class I override the install, rollback, commit and uninstall methods.

From the setup project, custom actions I add my custom library project output to each available folder. (Install Uninstall, Commit, and Rollback)

I find that there isn’t a corresponding folder for other install methods.

What should I do if I decide to override other methods like OnBeforeInstall or OnAfterInstall?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841423/unregister-an-ocx-in-onbeforeinstall-event-of-installer-class-then-try-to-regi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add your Custom Action primary project output to the Install folder, then I think the following methods will be called in this order:

1. OnBeforeInstall
2. Install
3. OnAfterInstall

The same goes for Uninstall, Commit and Rollback. So the OnBeforeXXX and OnAfterXXX methods don't require their own folder.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. Some other error was preventing the onbefore event from firing.

Comment: It can be quite hard to debug a setup project. The best way I know of is to right-click on the project in the Visual Studio Solution Explorer and select Install. This launches the installer. Then attach the debugger to the .msi process. If "Break on all exceptions" is checked, then you'll trap any errors that occur. You can also set break points in your custom action methods.