# unregister an .ocx in 'onbeforeinstall' event of Installer class then try to register it on install but couldnt done

Tags: c#-3.0, setup-project, setup-deployment, dllregistration

Hi ,

I tried to unregister and delete an `.ocx` & a `.dll` from the `System32(XP 32 bit os)/SysWow64(64bit OS)` of the machine using C# code. I had written the Unregister & Delete code in the override method `OnBeforeInstall(IDictionary savedState)` of installer class.When I tried to install the .msi the files(.ocx & .dll) get Unregistered, but at the install completes the new files not get registred ie its not present in the System32 folder.

Is the `OnBeforeInstall` event deletes the new files?

Please refer : http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Installation/MSI/Q_23525069.html

http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/DotNet/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.setup/2004-09/0145.html